# NumPy - 4-dimensional array appearing as 2-dimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras

I'm working on a coreference resolution model and am trying to feed a large matrix of data into my CNN's input layer. For illustration purposes, I have truncated my data to work with more manageable numbers.

### Format Data Function

```py
EMBEDDING_DIM = 400

...

@staticmethod
def get_train_data(data: DefaultDict[ClusteredDictKey, PreCoCoreferenceDatapoint], embedding_model) -> Tuple[List[Tensor], List[Tensor]]:
    """
    (n_samples, n_words, n_attributes (word embedding, pos, etc))
    [ [ [ word_embedding, pos ] ] ]

    xtrain[sentence_sample][word_position][attribute]
    xtrain[0][0] -> first word's attributes in first sentence
    xtrain[37][5] -> sixth word's attributes in 38th sentence
    xtrain[0][0][0] -> word_embedding
    xtrain[0][0][1] -> pos one-hot encoding
    """
    xtrain = []
    ytrain = []
    pos_onehot = PreCoParser.get_pos_onehot() # dictionary mapping POS to one-hot encoding

    for key, value in data.items():
        training_data = []

        sentence_embeddings = PreCoParser.get_embedding_for_sent(key.sentence, embedding_model) # Returns tensor (ndarray) of shape: (tokens_in_sent, EMBEDDING_DIM)
        pos = PreCoParser.get_pos_onehot_for_sent(key.sentence, pos_onehot) # Returns tensor (ndarray) of shape: (45,)

        assert sentence_embeddings.shape == (len(key.sentence), EMBEDDING_DIM)
        assert pos.shape == (len(key.sentence), 45)

        for i, embedding in enumerate(sentence_embeddings):
            training_data.append(np.asarray([embedding, np.asarray(pos[i])]))

        cluster_indices = list(sum([cluster.indices for cluster in value], ()))
        # Delete every third element to remove sentence index
        del cluster_indices[0::3]

        if len(training_data) > 0:
            xtrain.append(np.asarray(training_data))
            ytrain.append(np.asarray(cluster_indices) / len(key.sentence)) # normalize output data

    gc.collect()
    return (np.asarray(xtrain), np.asarray(ytrain))
```

### Abbreviated Issue

In short, I have a NumPy array that I am able to successfully run the following assert on:

```py
assert self.xtrain[0][0][0].shape == (EMBEDDING_DIM,)
```

implying, to me at least, that the array contains 4 dimensions, with the final vector containing EMBEDDING_DIM number of elements (400 in my case).

However, running the following code yields a weird result:

```py
>>> self.xtrain.shape
(500,) 
>>> self.xtrain[0].shape # on sentence with 11 words
(11,2)
>>> self.xtrain[0][0].shape # two attributes
(2,)
>>> self.xtrain[0][0][0].shape
(400,)
>>> self.xtrain[0][0][1].shape
(45,)
```

where `500` refers to my truncated number of samples (and all outputs are correct with what I expected). Additionally, when feeding this data through a simple Keras Conv2D input layer, I am greeted with the following error:

```
    self.model.fit(self.xtrain, self.ytrain, epochs=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1154, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 135, in standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (499, 1)
```

I'll happily post more code, need be, but any help at this current point would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check the `dtype` at each level as well.  It appears that `xtrain` is a 1d array of `object`.  One, maybe all elements are (11,2) arrays, object as well.  It's the mix of shapes at the lowest level, 400 and 45, that's preventing you from getting a n-d array all the way down.

Comment: You're totally right, my dtypes are all intermingled. From outter to inner, they are: `object`, `object`, `float32`, `uint8`. I assume my next step is to normalize the `dtype` into `float32`?

Comment: You get object dtype when dimensions don't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who may find this in the future, the issue was partially correctly pointed out by hpaulj. The other issue I was facing was with my data parsing. I ultimately converted the input data to a NumPy array of shape `(n_training_samples, INPUT_MAXLEN, 2, EMBEDDING_DIM)`. Once I normalized the structure of the matrix and removed arrays with `dtype='object'`, everything worked perfectly.

I referred to this website to effectively initialize an empty NumPy array: http://akuederle.com/create-numpy-array-with-for-loop

Final code:

```py
EMBEDDING_DIM = 400

...
@staticmethod
def get_train_data(data: DefaultDict[ClusteredDictKey, PreCoCoreferenceDatapoint], inputmaxlen: int, embedding_model) -> Tuple[List[Tensor], List[Tensor]]:
    """
    (n_samples, n_words, n_attributes (word embedding, pos, etc))
    [ [ [ word_embedding, pos ] ] ]

    xtrain[sentence_sample][word_position][attribute]
    xtrain[37][5] -> sixth word's attributes in 38th sentence (np.ndarray containing two np.ndarrays)
    xtrain[0][0][0] -> word_embedding (np.ndarray)
    xtrain[0][0][1] -> pos one-hot encoding (np.ndarray)
    """
    xtrain = np.empty((len(data), inputmaxlen, 2, EMBEDDING_DIM))
    ytrain = []
    pos_onehot = PreCoParser.get_pos_onehot()

    for i, (key, value) in enumerate(data.items()):
        training_data = []

        sentence_embeddings = PreCoParser.get_embedding_for_sent(key.sentence, embedding_model)
        pos = PreCoParser.get_pos_onehot_for_sent(key.sentence, pos_onehot)
        assert sentence_embeddings.shape == (len(key.sentence), EMBEDDING_DIM)
        assert pos.shape == (len(key.sentence), 45)

        for j, word_embeddings in enumerate(sentence_embeddings):
            pos_embeddings = sequence.pad_sequences([pos[j]], maxlen=EMBEDDING_DIM, dtype='float32', padding='post')[0]
            xtrain[i][j][0] = word_embeddings
            xtrain[i][j][1] = pos_embeddings

        cluster_indices = list(sum([cluster.indices for cluster in value], ()))
        # Delete every third element to remove sentence index
        del cluster_indices[0::3]

        ytrain.append(np.asarray(cluster_indices) / len(key.sentence))

    gc.collect()
    return (np.asarray(xtrain, dtype='float32'), np.asarray(ytrain, dtype='float32'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to leave this as a comment but because my reputation is not >50, it wouldn't let me :(

The only guess that I'm making with the error is that for model.fit() you've misplaced `ytrain` with `xtrain`, since for `ytrain` I could imagine an input of shape (499, 1). I'm afraid I would need more code for when the model is fed with the input data and labels.